Cross or left arrow in wizard started in a details screen
Dashboard -> list of devices -> device details -> start installation action
Dashboard -> list of devices -> create device system action -> success ui state -> start installation now action
Currently I don't use any modals for above cases, the action starts in a full screen with appbar as every screen before, the first page is a kind of welcome to the wizard page (with don't show again checkbox). In this wizard there are multiple chapters, each chapter has a start and finish screen, currently using the arrow left icon in the appbar and as title always the same text, the content below the appbar changes in each wizard step. In most of the steps we intercept back navigation with a close whole wizard confirmation dialog. Some stakeholders may tell we should use the cross icon in that screen, I myself am not sure, I'm using the left arrow for now.
Note: it's an Android app, the iOS guys used a modal with cross X for it, but I tend to stick with the arrow, am not able to really argument it correctly yet though.

Some mockup or image; or is your application a top secret CIA information?
